# value returned by a function is disappearing

Tags: python, return, return-type

I have 2 functions: `check_question_count()` that asks a user to give an input of a number between 1 and 15 , validates the input, then returns it; `random_question()` function takes that returned number and generates a number of questions.

The issue is that the returned value from the first function does not seem to  be returned, because i get an error that says: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'q_count'` referenced before assignment.

```
def random_question():
    check_question_count()
    q_index = 1
    global saved_question_count
    saved_question_count = int(q_count)
    print('Awesome! you will be asked ', saved_question_count,' randomly selected questions out of the total of 15 questions available.')
    #Using a while loop to print out a randomly selected question:
    while q_count != 0:
       b = len(questions_list) - 1
       rand_num = random.randint(0,b)
       global selected_question
       selected_question = questions_list[rand_num]
       print('\n')
       print(q_index,'.',selected_question)
       global user_answer
       user_answer = input('Your answer is: ').capitalize()
       #Using a function to validate the user_answer input:
       check_submitted_answers(user_answer)
       questions_list.remove(selected_question)
       questions_list =  questions_list
       q_count = q_count - 1
       q_index = q_index +1
           

#4- Function to check the question count input and make sure its a number between 1 to 15:
def check_question_count():
        global q_count
        q_count = input('\nHow many questions do you like to take? You can choose a number between 1 to 15: ')
        while True:
          if q_count not in ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15']:
            print('Error: Invalid input! Please type in only a number between 1 and 15: ')
            q_count = input('\nHow many questions do you like to take? You can choose a number between 1 to 15: ')
            continue
          else:
            return q_count

random_question()
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `q_count = check_question_count()` in `random_question`

Comment: Compare the line where you call `check_question_count` with other lines where you call functions and use their return values. What's different?

Comment: when you call a function, if you want to make use of the return value you have to assign the result of the call to a variable e.g. `myvar= check_question_count()` ... e.g. here you could name it q_count `q_count = check_question_count()` ... but note that this is a different `q_count` variable from the one inside the other function (even though in this case it will have the same value, since we are returning one into the other)

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your code. One is severe, the other is not.

The root cause of the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'q_count' referenced before assignment` is the line `q_count = q_count - 1` in `random_question()`. This supposed to *modify* the variable, but that variable is supposed to be global, and thus, not writable. This makes python believe you have a *local*, modifiable variable `q_count`, and thus, all the mentions of it in the current scope must mean this local one - and when you reference it first, it **is** referenced before assigned.

One solution would be to just use the global version, i.e. `global saved_question_count, q_count`. Another one would be to remove the line `q_count = q_count - 1` - but you probably need that line. A third one would be to create a new (local) variable, and initialize it with `q_count`.

The best solution would be (that also fixes the second problem of unnecessary global variables) is to just return the value. Others have already explained that in detail.

Answer (score 0):

You are not saving the returned value in any given variable i.e instead of

`check_question_count()`

try:

`q_count = check_question_count()`

in order to save the returned value in a variable.

You should also look into the proper use of `global` keyword because it is being used unnecessarily here-[Use of "global" keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python.)

Comment: The poster already seems to have saved the result into a global variable. I agree that returning it and not using `global` is better, but the cause of the problem is not adressed in this answer.

Comment: @Sasszem Yes, they have created a global variable but that is not how a global variable is used. By saving the value in a variable and removing global, the error will go away.